# use editText to reorder an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, collections, android-recyclerview

I'm using an ArrayList to populate a RecyclerView, and I have attached Buttons that point up and down to each element of the RecycledView. I would like to set an `OnClickListener` to my `update` button which intends move that respective elements position up or down in the ArrayList. This will occur in my RecyclerView's Adapter class inside  the following method:

```
onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
      //updateBtn is declared and initialized in the ViewHolder   
      holder.upBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
          //arrayList.set(newPosition, object?);
          notifiyDataSetChange();
      });
}
```

In this case I know I should subtract 1 from the current position in order to make that element move up in the list and add 1 for that element to move down. **BUT** I feel like I'm missing some logic here and I'm really not sure what do.  How could I make to above code re-order my list in that particular case move the element up e.g. from position 1 in the array to position 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Collections.swap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#swap(java.util.List,%20int,%20int)) method:

```
Collections.swap(arrayList, position, newPosition);
```